# ThisWorkbook.close Does Not Work Consistently

Tags: excel, vba

ThisWorkbook.Close does not work the same depending how the macro is executed. If the macro executes by a user clicking the workbook button, when everything is complete and the macro finishes, the `ThisWorkbook.Close` closes the workbook as expected. If the macro executes automatically upon workbook open `(Workbook_Open())`, the ThisWorkbook.Close does not close the workbook.

Upon opening the workbook, the `Workbook_Open()` calls the main routine Notes.OpenForm. The `Workbook_Open()` is in module `"ThisWorkbook"` and OpenForm is in module `"Notes"`.

If the user clicks a button, it executes `SendETSNote_Click()` which also calls `Notes.OpenForm`. `SendETSNote` is in `Sheet1(ETS Notes Form)` module and calls OpenForm from module `Notes`.

I have included the code for the `Workbook_Open()`, `SendETSNote()` and the routine which attempts to close the workbook - `Done_Click()` stored in the `Notes` module.

More background: OpenForm resizes the workbook to a minimized size and opens a User Form. I'd prefer the user not see the Excel workbook and only see the User Form. After the user fills the form and its contents are sent via email, the user can click "Done" which should close the form and close the workbook.

As stated, if the macro launches via the Workbook_Open(), the ThisWorkbook.Close does not close the workbook. If the macro launches by `SendETSNote_Click()`, the workbook closes.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Notes.OpenForm
End Sub


Private Sub SendETSNote_Click()
    Call Notes.OpenForm
End Sub


Sub Done_Click()
'
' Upon document close, shut down Outlook if running and started within this code
'

    If outlookRunning = True Then
        'If we started Outlook from within this code, then close it
        oOutlookApp.Quit
    End If
'
'   Turn off screen updating so user doesn't see resizing
'   Resize Excel sheet to max before closing
'   Close without saving changes
'

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
'
'   Close the form
'

    Unload Me

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    ThisWorkbook.Close False
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I expect the ThisWorkbook.Close to close the workbook no matter how the macro launches.

Comment: Is `Done_Click()` in the same module as `Workbook_Open()`? Please [edit] your post to clearly separate the modules if that's not the case - note, `Unload Me` would throw an error if it's in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Also... I'd remove `Unload Me` altogether. It makes no sense to unload a form that still has code to run, and closing `ThisWorkbook` will unload it all anyway.

Comment: *OpenForm resizes the workbook to a minimized size and opens a User Form. I'd prefer the user not see the Excel workbook and only see the User Form* - you're in Excel, no use being in denial about it. If you need a standalone app, then you should write a standalone app, not something that's embedded in an Excel workbook. That said `ThisWorkbook.Close` leaves Excel open; consider `Application.Quit` if you want to close *everything*.

Comment: I've tested popping a form with a button that closes `ThisWorkbook` on open, and it works perfectly fine. Are you running into any errors? Do you have `On Error Resume Next` anywhere?

Comment: As stated in my question, Done_Click() is NOT in the same module as Workbook_Open(). There are three modules involved. Workbook_Open() has to be in ThisWorkbook module to execute when the workbook is open. The Done_Click() is generated automatically and placed in the Notes module when I create the form.

Comment: I know where `Workbook_Open` needs to be, thank you. But I can't guess that `Done_Click` is only deceptively a click handler (don't do that!), when it's actually a public macro in a standard module. Still trying to work out where `SendETSNote_Click` is. Don't you think readers would have an easier time figuring out what's where if the code block didn't look like everything was in one place? Adding "In {module name}:` on top of each separate code block would go a long way towards clarifying what's where.

Comment: Also, you're not showing where `Done_Click` is being invoked from (BTW it can't have been generated automatically if it's in a standard module), and the most likely source of anything that could possibly go wrong is in `Notes.OpenForm`, which you haven't included.

Comment: As stated in my question, Done_Click() is NOT in the same module as Workbook_Open(). There are three modules involved. Workbook_Open() has to be in ThisWorkbook module to execute when the workbook is open. The Done_Click() is generated automatically and placed in the Notes module when I create the form.

Comment: I am working inside a pharma company. Introducing a standalone app would be very difficult. The Excel macro is pushing the edge of complaint behavior. Knowing the users of the macro, I'd prefer to hide Excel to keep it really simple.

Comment: I don't want to use Application.Quit because many users will have other Excel workbooks open at the same time. Application.Quit will close all of them - most annoying to the users. 

I read through your article - thanks. I'll try those suggestions.